# Pass Contact form 7 variable to screen

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, contact-form-7

Using contact form 7 I am posting an API string, and receiving the response in $Body.

I want to print this response to the screen, but var_dump, echo, and print haven't worked to try and display the value on the page.

I have managed to log in to the error log but want to know is there a way for me to pass this variable to the page?

```
add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent','Kiri_cf7_api_sender');

 function Kiri_cf7_api_sender ( $contact_form) {
     if ( $contact_form->title === 'Quote_form')
     {
        $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

        if ($submission) 
        {
            $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
            
            $name = $posted_data["your-name"];
            $surname = $posted_data["your-name2"];
            $phone = $posted_data["tel-922"];
            
            //example url//
            $url = www.mytestapi.com?$name&$surname&$phone;
                        
            $response = wp_remote_post ($url);
            $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );
            
                     ob_start();                     // start buffer capture

    var_dump($name);
    var_dump($surname);
    var_dump($phone);
    
    $contents = ob_get_contents();  // put the buffer into a variable
    ob_end_clean();                 // end capture
    error_log($contents); 
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Hi.  I would recommend your process uses the CF7 DOM events https://contactform7.com/dom-events/ and you trigger some ajax to post your API call, then return some HTML or JSON back to the form.  Specifically, I would refer to `document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit')`

Comment: Hi. I am not entirely familiar with Ajax, could you explain in a bit more detail for me. I understand that I will have to use ```document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event )```, to fire off after my forms submission.

Comment: Quite frankly, this would take a little while to create a script that uses php/ajax to get your response and push it back to the form. Specifically, you'd have to localize scripts, add js file, php functions.  I'd help you refine something, but I can't really write the whole thing for you.

Answer (score 0):

The [Smart Grid-layout](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-grid-layout/) extension v4.11 (releasing this week, v4.11rc1 is available on the GitHub [repo](https://github.com/aurovrata/cf7-grid-layout/releases/tag/4.11rc1)) includes a handy filter to add custom HTML to the response output,

```
add_filter( 'cf7sg_submission_success_message','change_submission_response',10,3);
/*
* filter the response message for a successfull submission including HTML markup.
* @param String $message to submit
* @param Array $data $field_name=>$value pair of submitted data.
* @param String $cf7key unique form key
* @return String a message which can include HTML markup.
*/
function change_submission_response($message, $data, $cf7key){
  //validate this is the correct form being submitted.
  if('my-form'==$cf7key ){
    $message = 'thank you, please track your request <a href="http://google.com">here</a>';
  }
  return $message;
}
```